# How onepica image cdn for magento exactly work with ftp?

Tags: php, magento, cdn

I am planning to use sub-domain for Magento media dir as a cdn.

Settings I did till so far :

magento store URL: example.com
Media dir url: cdn.example.com/media/

So I installed onepica ImageCDN extension and setup it for FTP.

Image CDN settings:
 Current Adapter: FTPS
 File Result Cache: In database (recommended)
 Cache Time-to-Live: 1440
 Verify File Size: Yes
 Image Compression: Use default

FTP/FTPS/SFTP:
 Server: cdn.example.com
 Port: 21
 User: user
 Pass: ***********
 FTP Passive Mode: No
 Base Directory: media
 Base Url: http://cdn.example.com/media
 Secure Base Url: http://cdn.example.com/media
 Direct URLs: Yes

Admin Settings:

1. Path: System -> configuration -> General -> Web -> UnsecureURL
   media dir path: {{unsecureurl}}/media
2. Path: System -> configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Storage Configuration for Media 
   media storage: File System, Environment Update Time: 3600

Then uploaded current media dir to cdn.example.com.

After all this

In frontend I can see old product images from cdn.example.com/media/ 
But new uploaded / updated product images are not visible and not fetching to CDN subdomain. (I can see these images in backend).

Kindly help me to find out what i did wrong?

also have some questions:

I am confused how exactly onepica will distribute the file for first time?

How Image CDN update file tie to time including thumbnail images from cache?

If new product images uploaded then thumbnail will generate, how ImageCDN will take care of it and when update?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question. The way that OnePica works is that no images are stored on the CDN by default. So any new products added will have there images served via your normal media directory, However after the initial request OnePica that takes that file and uploads it to the CDN so all subsequent requests are served via the CDN. This goes for thumbnails and large images.

OnePica stores its records in a database table to see what has been uploaded and what hasnt and if the file name is different. Hence a new upload based on a change.

As per your first question I have never used my own subdomain to distribute images so I cant comment, I have always stuck to main stream providers so Rackspace cloud and that has worked fine for me.